# push the application to /system/app/ and upload .so library

Tags: android

I have a .so library in my application. If it install to /data/app normal, it will appear /lib/*.so file normal in /data/data/ corresponding package catalogue and it can upload and operation.

But if I push the application to /system/app/, the library can not appear in /data/data/ corresponding package catalogue. I move the library manually and restart, the library file disappears.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Place your so files in /system/lib